# Probability: cards question

Tags: probability

Alice and Bob get 5 cards each from a deck of cards (52 cards). What is the probability that at least one of them has quartet (e.g.,bob has 4 queens and 1 ace and alice has 5 different cards)?

I assumed Bob got the cards first and split it into 3 cases. First case: Bob got a quartet and Alice didn't. Second case: Bob didn't get a quartet and Alice did. Third Case: They both have a quartet. But this way of solution seems complicated to me.

Comment: Is 4 queens an example, or a requirement? I suspect you meant "e.g.". Anyways, what have you tried?

Comment: Fixed the question.

Comment: Another option is add the probabilities that Alice obtains four of a kind and Bob obtain obtains four of a kind.  Doing so counts each case in which they both get four of a kind twice, so we need to subtract the probability that they both get four of a kind.

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you have tried and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: On this site, it is expected that you include your own attempt when you pose a question.

Comment: It got too complicated and I failed solving it.

Comment: Can you find the probability that Alice obtains four of a kind?

Comment: Is it 13*48/C(52,5) ?

Comment: I know how to get the probability for one person who got 5 cards but not between two people